# How do i safely store the contents of a file in my app?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Iam trying to make a music streaming app,so I want to know how I can prevent the people from copying the songs and redistribute it.i want to make the directory in which the music is stored much safe,but not allowing the people to copy the contents of the folder.

Comment: Storing files in your apps *Internal storage directories* is the safest. Its encrypted on Android 10 and above https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific if you did bundle the music in your apk that could be extracted. Another option is to have the app download the content on launch

Comment: I suppose the key point is how to encrypt instead of store. if user using the app with emulator, there is no limitation for him to access the file, you need to encrypt and decrypt by you self, with SSL, it is easy to handle it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.